# Android: How to set recenter intervall of myLocationOverlay

Tags: android, maps, center

Using myLocationOverlay, the map continuously recenters on the current position. How can I change the interval, I think, for the user it would be enough, if the map would recenter every minute or so.

Thanx,
Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 500, 0, myLocationListener);